# Python save every entry in list=[] on tkinter

Tags: list, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm still new with python gui programming. 
I want to open two list . one for entry on the other for the button . Than i want to extend  this. But my problem is i get only one value . i want to save e.g.
list_one_entryfield=[100,32,53] and  list_two_button=[100,200] 
-with extend->newList=[100,32,53,100,200] 
my code:

```
def txtOk(EN_number):
    EN_number = txtDisplay.get()    
    #print(EN_number)
    listEN=[]
    listEN.append(EN_number)
    print(listEN)    
    return listEN

def addNumber(BN_number): 
    #print(BN_number)

    listBN=[]
    listBN.append(BN_number)
    print(listBN)
    return listBN 
BN_txtOk= Button(frame2,text ='OK',bg = 'green',fg='white', padx=38, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : txtOk(txtDisplay))
BN_txtOk.grid(row=0, column= 0)

frame3= Frame(root1)
frame3.configure(bg='light blue')
frame3.pack(side=TOP)
BN_water= Button(frame3, text ='100ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : addNumber('100'))
BN_water.pack(side = LEFT)
BN_water1= Button(frame3, text ='200ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : addNumber('200'))
BN_water1.pack(side = LEFT)        
BN_water2= Button(frame3, text ='300ml',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : addNumber('300'))
BN_water2.pack(side = LEFT)        
BN_water3= Button(frame3, text ='0,5L',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : addNumber('500'))
BN_water3.pack(side = LEFT)
BN_water4= Button(frame3, text ='1L',bg ='blue',fg = 'white',padx=8, pady= 8, bd= 8, command = lambda : addNumber('1000'))
BN_water4.pack(side = LEFT)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "toolbar"? What toolbar are you talking about? Is this something unique to a specific platform?

Comment: i mean the taskbar right side, where are the  icons from charge or speaker or open devices and printers.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7  64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your program to a .exe file you can use py2exe: http://www.py2exe.org/.

This should create a .exe file that can run on any Windows computer (no need to install python there).

Edit: note that when you convert your program the user will not see your print statements. You can convert them to a Tkinter messagebox:

```
from tkinter import messagebox

messagebox.showinfo("water drink program", "You drank enough water")
```